# Can anyone help me with this piece of code stated below?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function evenNumbers() {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<=20;i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            document.write(i+"\n");
        }
    } 
} 
</script>
```

I am trying to print the number using the `\n` escape sequence but it is not working. Can anyone please help.
Note: I don't want to use `<br/>` tag and also i have tried `/\n/` and `/\r/`. But it is not working.

Comment: @CasperOne: Can you tell me how it is not a real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple line break doesn't mean anything in HTML, it's simply whitespace.

Either print everything inside a `<pre>` tag, which preserves whitespace formatting, or use HTML tags like `<br>`, `<li>` or whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, for the matter a testcase using `<pre>` in OP's code --> https://tinker.io/bcfe8

Comment: Can you please tell the modified code then?

Answer (score 1):

The `'\n'` character would only be reflected if your content is inside a `<pre>` tag. Use line breaks inside the html instead: `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks! I know it is working with the breakline tag, but what is the reason for the new line escape sequence not working? what is a <pre> tag? and do you mean that javascript does not support the \n inside the document.write() method?

Comment: @AnkurSharma <pre> displays the content inside of it preformatted. Otherwise it would be formatted by the document, meaning all of it would be on one line. In terms of HTML the '\n' means nothing, it's just another character.

Comment: D: i am using the \n inside a method which belongs to java script and not HTML.
<pre> tag preserves the formatting. It works and it belongs to html not javascript.

Comment: @Ankur You're working in an HTML document though! You're modifying an HTML document using Javascript. So HTML formatting options apply.

Comment: @decez: Thanks. So you mean that i have no other option rather than using the break line <br /> tag>?

Comment: @Ankur Right, that's what I said. :)